# How can I list code with alignment and syntax highlighting?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, code, tabbing

I would like to effectively typeset code in a proportional font with syntax highlighting and horizontal alignment. How can I do that?

The package *listings* offers syntax highlighting but not alignment. If I use a proportional font, there is no way to horizontally align text as far as I know.

The environment *tabbing* allows alignment but not automatic syntax highlighting. If I want to have colors, I need to put them there manually. Also, the inside of *tabbing* is normal text, so quotation marks and apostrophes are changed, and whitespace collapses to a single space.

I didn't manage to combine these two environments. Every time, it didn't compile or looked wrong.

---

Here is an example of how it is supposed to look. I made it with tabbing using some workarounds and manual highlighting.

[image: example of code listing in a proportional font with alignment and syntax highlighting]

If I remove the highlighting and workarounds, the code of it is this:

```
\begin{tabbing}
    (defclass request () \\
    \hspace{1.5em} \= ( \= (url \= :reader request-url \\
        \>  \>  \> :initarg :url \\
        \>  \>  \> :type string} \\
        \>  \>  \> :documentation "Request URL.") \\
        \>  \> (method \= :reader request-method \\
        \>  \>  \> :initarg :method \\
        \>  \>  \> :initform :get \\
        \>  \>  \> :type keyword\\
        \>  \>  \> :documentation "Request method, e.g :get, :post.") \\
        \>  \> (parameters \= :reader request-parameters \\
        \>  \>  \> :initarg :parameters \\
        \>  \>  \> :initform nil \\
        \>  \>  \> :type association-list \\
        \>  \>  \> :documentation "The request parameters, as an association list.")) \\
        \> (:documentation "A general HTTP request."))
\end{tabbing}
```

Comment: Have you tried package [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted)? Warning: It needs `--shell-escape` flag while compiling.

Comment: How would minted help with alignment of text in proportional font compared to listing?